# How do I change the style property - textInputStyleName of a combobox at runtime?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a prompt string to be displayed in my combobox - this needs to be displayed in *italics*. When user makes any selection from the list - i need to change the style of the displayed content.

My css file:

```
.promptStyle
{
    fontStyle: italic;
}
ComboBox.withPrompt
{
    color: #FF0000;
    fontWeight: normal;
    textInputStyleName: promptStyle;
}
.regularStyle
{
    fontStyle: normal;
}
ComboBox.withoutPrompt
{
    color: black;
    fontWeight: normal;
    textInputStyleName: regularStyle;
}
```

My MXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" 
            minWidth="955" minHeight="600" initialize="init()">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        private var content:Array=new Array("Red", "Blue", "Green");

        private function init():void {
            StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("combos/combo_style.swf");
        }

        private function changeStyle():void {
            var index:int = promptBox.selectedIndex;
            if(index != -1)
                promptBox.setStyle("styleName","withoutPrompt");
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:ComboBox id="promptBox" prompt="Select a color" dataProvider="{content}"
        styleName="withPrompt" change="changeStyle()"/>
</mx:Application>
```

I am able to see the style change happening because the color changes; but the change specific to textInputStyleName does not get applied. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not my area of expertise.  It doesn't look like you have this set up right though.  You don't want to change the styleName to a string.  You want to change it the CSS Reference.  Try removing the quotes from the setStyle method: promptBox.setStyle("styleName",withoutPrompt);

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the style to the internal `TextInput` subcomponent, but for this you have to derive your own `PromptingComboBox` to access the protected [textInput](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBase.html#textInput) property.

I think the following class does basically what you want and should give you an idea:

```
public class PromptingComboBox extends ComboBox implements IFactory
{
    private var _dropDown: List = null;

    public function PromptingComboBox()
    {
        super.dropdownFactory = this;
    }

    public function newInstance(): *
    {
        _dropDown = new List();
        _dropDown.addEventListener(ListEvent.CHANGE, onChangeDropDownList);
        return _dropDown;
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        this.textInput.setStyle("fontStyle", "italic");
    }

    private function onChangeDropDownList(event: Event): void
    {
        this.textInput.setStyle("fontStyle", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you :) I was able to get it to work by sub-classing ComboBox as you suggested. Updating textInputStyleName in my css would have been a much cleaner solution for me since this is a huge existing application and now i have to get into several MXMLs and change the control to use the custom control instead - im guessing this is a bug in flex?

Anyways, thanks for your help!